# Android Room doesn't allow me to do the one-to-N relationship multiple times

Tags: android, sql, kotlin, android-room

I have implemented a DB where I have two one-to-many relationships but it would seem that room does not allow it. Is that so?

The entities are:

```
@Entity(tableName = "arete_sheet")
data class EAreteSheet(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sheet") val form: Sheets,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "version") val version: Int,
)

@Entity(tableName = "arete_sheet_paragraph")
data class EAreteSheetParagraph(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "arete_sheet_id") val sheet: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "name") val name: String
)

@Entity(tableName = "arete_sheet_form")
data class EAreteSheetForm(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "arete_sheet_paragraph_id") val paragraph: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fieldType") val fieldType: FieldType,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cell") val cell: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "label") val label: String
)
```

To solve the schema I have implemented these join classes:

```
data class EAreteSheetWithParagraph(
    @Embedded val sheet: EAreteSheet,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "arete_sheet_id"
    )
    val paragraph: List<EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm>
)
data class EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm(
    @Embedded val paragraph: EAreteSheetParagraph,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "arete_sheet_paragraph_id"
    )
    val forms: List<EAreteSheetForm>
)
```

This is the DAO implementation:

```
  @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM arete_sheet")
    suspend fun getSheetWithParagraphsAndForms(): List<EAreteSheetWithParagraph>
```

This is the mistake he gives me in the building phase:

```
app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/it/ximplia/agri2000/model/db/dao/AreteSheetDAO_Impl.java:203: error: constructor EAreteSheetWithParagraph in class EAreteSheetWithParagraph cannot be applied to given types;
              _item = new EAreteSheetWithParagraph();
                      ^
  required: EAreteSheet,List<EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm>
  found: no arguments
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
app/build/generated/source/kapt/debug/it/ximplia/agri2000/model/db/dao/AreteSheetDAO_Impl.java:204: error: sheet has private access in EAreteSheetWithParagraph
              _item.sheet = _tmpSheet;
```

I think that Room does not allow to resolve dependencies in cascade but I would like to know if someone was successful or if I made a mistake before changing the code.

Answer (score 0):

In **EAreteSheetWithParagraph** you are specifying a list of **EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm**'s

as per :-

```
val paragraph: List<EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm>
```

The @Relation will try to ascertain the columns as per the **EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm** form class, which is not an Entity. You should change the @Relation to specify the appropriate entity (i.e. the **EAreteSheetParagraph**) using the **entity** parameter.

So **EAreteSheetWithParagraph** should be something like :-

```
data class EAreteSheetWithParagraph(
    @Embedded val sheet: EAreteSheet,
    @Relation(
        entity = EAreteSheetParagraph::class,
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "arete_sheet_id" 
    )
    val paragraph: List<EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm>
)
```

However, I don't believe that you are getting that far, as the messages appear to be complaining about the **sheet** variable which has a type of Sheets (and that the variable is private).

Without adding the entity= parameter then the compile, if it reached that stage, would fail with :-

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
error: The class must be either @Entity or @DatabaseView. - a.a.so68953488kotlinroommany1_n.EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm
E:\AndroidStudioApps\SO68953488KotlinRoomMany1N\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\a\a\so68953488kotlinroommany1_n\EAreteSheetWithParagraph.java:12: error: Cannot find the child entity column `arete_sheet_id` in a.a.so68953488kotlinroommany1_n.EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm. Options: 
    private final java.util.List<a.a.so68953488kotlinroommany1_n.EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm> paragraph = null;
                                                                                               ^
The class must be either @Entity or @DatabaseView. - a.a.so68953488kotlinroommany1_n.EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm
```

> I think that Room does not allow to resolve dependencies in cascade but I would like to know if someone was successful or if I made a mistake before changing the code.

As indicated above, I believe the issue is mistakes so :-

**Proof of concept**

Based upon your code the following shows that nested/multiple 1-n's do work:-

Using your code BUT with the following changes (to avoid issues and simplify) :-

```
@Entity(tableName = "arete_sheet_form")
data class EAreteSheetForm(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "arete_sheet_paragraph_id") val paragraph: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "fieldType") val fieldType: /* FieldType */ String, // changed for convenience/brevity
    @ColumnInfo(name = "cell") val cell: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "label") val label: String
)
```

- fieldType' stype changed from FieldType to String so no need for extra class and type converters.

and

```
@Entity(tableName = "arete_sheet")
data class EAreteSheet(
    @PrimaryKey val id: Long,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "sheet") val form: /*Sheets*/ String, // changed for convenience/brevity
    @ColumnInfo(name = "version") val version: Int,
)
```

- Sheets type substituted with String

EAreteSheetWithParagraph as above

EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm changed to

```
data class EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm(
    @Embedded val paragraph: EAreteSheetParagraph,
    @Relation(
        parentColumn = "id",
        entityColumn = "arete_sheet_paragraph_id",
        entity = EAreteSheetForm::class
    )
    val forms: List<EAreteSheetForm>
)
```

- i.e. the entity parameter has been added according to my preference to always code the entity parameter.

AreteSheetDao used :-

```
@Dao
abstract class AreteSheetDAO {

    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(eAreteSheet: EAreteSheet): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(eAreteSheetParagraph: EAreteSheetParagraph): Long
    @Insert
    abstract fun insert(eAreteSheetForm: EAreteSheetForm): Long

    @Transaction
    @Query("SELECT * FROM arete_sheet")
    abstract fun getSheetWithParagraphsAndForms(): List<EAreteSheetWithParagraph>

}
```

Code in an Activity :-

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var db: TheDatabase
    lateinit var dao: AreteSheetDAO
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        db = TheDatabase.getInstance(this)
        dao = db.getDao()

        var s1 = dao.insert(EAreteSheet(10,"Sheet1",1))
        var s2 = dao.insert(EAreteSheet(20,"Sheet2",1))
        var p1 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetParagraph(100,s1,"Para1 (Sheet1)"))
        var p2 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetParagraph(101,s1,"Para2 (Sheet1)"))
        var p3 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetParagraph(201,s2,"Para3 (Sheet2)"))
        var p4 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetParagraph(202,s2,"Para4 (Sheet2)"))
        var f1 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetForm(1000,p1,"typex","cellx","Form1"))
        var f2 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetForm(1001,p1,"typex","cellx","Form2"))
        var f3 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetForm(1002,p1,"typex","cellx","Form3"))
        var f4 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetForm(1010,p2,"typex","cellx","Form4"))
        var f5 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetForm(1011,p2,"typex","cellx","Form5"))
        var f6 = dao.insert(EAreteSheetForm(1020,p3,"typex","cellx","Form6"))
        val TAG = "ARETEINFO"
        for(sw: EAreteSheetWithParagraph in dao.getSheetWithParagraphsAndForms()) {
            Log.d(TAG,"Sheet ID is ${sw.sheet.id} Form is ${sw.sheet.form} Version is ${sw.sheet.version}" )
            for(pf: EAreteSheetParagraphWithForm in sw.paragraph) {
                Log.d(TAG,"\tPara is ${pf.paragraph.name} etc")
                for(f: EAreteSheetForm in pf.forms) {
                    Log.d(TAG,"\t\tForm is ${f.label}")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As can be seen, some data is loaded, 2 Sheets, each with 2 paragraphs and then 4 forms distributed unevenly (3 to para1, 2 to para2, 1 to para3, 0 to para4).

The data is then extracted *(as array of EAreteSheetWithParagraph)*, the array traversed *(traversing the underlying arrays of paragraphs and forms within paragraphs)* and output to the log the **Result** being :-

```
D/ARETEINFO: Sheet ID is 10 Form is Sheet1 Version is 1
D/ARETEINFO:    Para is Para1 (Sheet1) etc
D/ARETEINFO:        Form is Form1
D/ARETEINFO:        Form is Form2
D/ARETEINFO:        Form is Form3
D/ARETEINFO:    Para is Para2 (Sheet1) etc
D/ARETEINFO:        Form is Form4
D/ARETEINFO:        Form is Form5
D/ARETEINFO: Sheet ID is 20 Form is Sheet2 Version is 1
D/ARETEINFO:    Para is Para3 (Sheet2) etc
D/ARETEINFO:        Form is Form6
D/ARETEINFO:    Para is Para4 (Sheet2) etc
```